# How to Calculate the Height and Width of Forms in Powerhsell?

Tags: powershell

Can someone help me in understanding how to calculate the Height and Width of a Powershell Forms. For Example I Created a blank Powershell form of Height 500 and Width 700 and now If want to place a Text box a little below from the top of the form what will be the height and width that I need to enter? and If I want to place a Button at middle of the Form? what will be the height and width that I need to enter? I am struggling with this calculation.

Comment: I think you can learn a lot [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/layout)

Comment: I'm not sure every time you are saying "Height and Width", you actually mean weight and width.  When dealing with form  objects you have an X and Y. I've done more of this in C#, and in that case it is Location.X and Location.Y.  What you have to realize is that Height/2 + Location.Y is the vertical center of a button, and Width/2 + Location.X is the horizontal center of a button.  With the form itself, all you have to do is divide the Height or Width by 2 and you have the center of the form.  You have to work the math out so  that the center of the button equals the center of the form.

Answer (score -1):

You should get the screen size and use the ratio to set position. The ratio is useful for different screen size.